# Is there a findById shortcut for the MongoDB shell?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongo-shell

The most common thing I do in the mongo DB shell is find objects by ID, eg:

```
db.collection.find({_id: ObjectId("55a3e051dc75954f0f37c2f2"})
```

I do this over and over and I find having to wrap the id with ObjectId over and over gets old. I wish I had a `findById`-like shorthand form like what mongoose provides. I feel like the shell ought to be smart enough to figure out what I mean here for example:

```
db.collection.find("55a3e051dc75954f0f37c2f2")
```

How might I do this? Or are there any alternative ways of querying by id in the mongo shell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shorthand for `find({_id: ObjectId("...")})` is `find(ObjectId("..."))`.

Answer (score 6):

Fortunately, you can extend the shell quite easily, for example by adding the following method to the [`~/.mongorc.js` file](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongo/#files) which is executed when you start the `mongo` client:

```
DBCollection.prototype.findById = function(id) {
    return db.getCollection(this._shortName).find( { "_id" : ObjectId(id) } );
}
```

Then you can execute something like `db.collection.findById("55a3e051dc75954f0f37c2f2")`